# Using COM binary serialization as C# and C++ undrestadable format

Tags: c#, c++, serialization, com

I work at high performance IPC between C# and C++ processes. I have already chosen IPC mechanism. But work on serialization compatible with native and managed sides. I am looking into protobuf. 
But appears that COM when used for IPC also does binary serialization. May be I can use it.

What is the library and methods I should look into? (just do not want to add protobuf if can)

Comment: What do you mean by COM Binary Serialization? COM does call serialization (RPC/Marshaling, etc.), not object serialization.

Comment: COM doesn't implement binary object serialization itself, just provides interfaces to implement it in your objects (primarily required for OLE objects embedding). See `IPersist`, `IPersistStorage`, `IPersistMemory`, `IPersistFile`, `IPersistStream` [documentation in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688695(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Rost, Thanks! I can use IPersist* pattern to ask COM devs to layout their objects into byte array.

Comment: @SimonMourier, thanks! You separated 2 items for me. Because I used to simple cases of WCF where serialization and RPC are not distinguished at first glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, COM can do that.  It is a fundamentally different approach from, say, proto-buf, it supports out-of-process servers.  In other words, you could write your C++ program as such a server and your client code could automatically start it and start calling methods implemented by the server.  The data you want to get across the process boundary can be passed through arguments of such a method.  The C# equivalent is Remoting or WCF.

Serialization is actually one of the weaker points in COM, you may have to provide additional code called a proxy/stub that knows how to encode the data passed through the arguments so it can be passed across the boundary.  There is a lot of tooling support for that, you start by describing the methods and their arguments in a language called IDL (Interface Description Language).  Which can then be automatically compiled into a proxy/stub DLL.  If the data you pass is particularly onerous then you may have to write a custom marshaller.  Or if it is particularly simple, restricting itself to the subset of types supported by COM automation then you may not need a proxy/stub at all and the standard marshaller can be used.  Which uses a *type library*, also auto-generated from the IDL.

Lots of flexibility here, but that certainly comes at a price.  COM is widely considered *difficult*.  Not easy to debug either when you have problems.  If "understandable" is your primary goal then do not consider COM, proto-buf is much easier to tackle.  One step down, named pipes or sockets are easy to get going in either runtime environment, but de/serializing the data is up to you.  You can make that understandable by using XML.

Comment: thanks! Seems serialization for COM is integrated only for simple types (bool, string, integer). Complex objects should be done by developers. I think if performance will be OK than stick with protobuf. But if bad I will going to ask C++ devs layout their objects tuning for objects at hand (e.g. make them implement IPersist*). For IPC we already evaluated with mem mapped files and named pipes and seems will stick with.